# Floating label is not respect the border area

Tags: angular, angular-material

I'm creating a form using angular material and using the `mat-form-field` with the `appearance = "outline"` property I'm having the image problem when the image loads and I click the input:

[image: mat-form-field error]

But when you click reload the page it is normally displayed as shown in this image:

[image: mat-form-field]

I've identified that this problem occurs when I load the page for the first time or by reloading using ctrl + F5.
This problem occurs with all inputs, including those that have a placeholder with only 3 letters and even without having an icon in the input as well.

Anyone know how I can adjust this?

Edit1 : follows the code of one of my inputs:

```
          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Sobrenome</mat-label>
            <input matInput formControlName="sobrenome">
            <mat-error
              *ngIf="firstForm.controls['sobrenome'].hasError('required') || firstForm.controls['sobrenome'].touched">
              Informe um sobrenome válido!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>



          <mat-form-field appearance="outline">
            <mat-label>Data de nascimento</mat-label>
            <input matInput [matDatepicker]="picker" formControlName="dataNasc">
            <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
            <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>
            <mat-error
              *ngIf="firstForm.controls['dataNasc'].hasError('required') || firstForm.controls['dataNasc'].touched">
              Informe uma data de nascimento válida!
            </mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
```

Comment: Please update your question with a source code example of the HTML used to create one of the inputs.

Comment: added code, tnks

Comment: on this page I have no style added. I added the HTML of the image input too.

Comment: Can you try `<mat-form-field [style.width.px]="300">` and see if that fixes it. I have a feeling this is a sizing issue.

Comment: did not work. Strange because after refreshing the page it works normally =(

Comment: How are you adding the image where is the `<mat-icon>` tag ?

Comment: is an image of the component itself, and even in those without icones the problem occurs.
https://material.angular.io/components/datepicker/overview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved, I had erased the standard subject matter statement from the angular material, added it again, and no longer presented the problem. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

Check your code errors with ng s --aot, this happen because you have template code errors.

Comment: I checked with this command but did not point to any errors in the template

Comment: Delete your label of your input and use the label as input placeholder instead.

Answer (score 0):

you should not use an image instead use material icon like this [blitzy](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-av8web?file=app/form-field-appearance-example.html)

```
<mat-icon matSuffix>calendar_today</mat-icon>
```

Comment: this occurs in all inputs, including those with no icon =(

Comment: Maybe you have some styles that are causing this check if you can reproduce it on my blitzy link

Comment: I can not simulate the problem in blitzy = (